# R shiny updating default numeric values in conditional panels

Tags: r, shiny

I'm facing the following problem: Dependent on the order of conditional Panels (actually the conditions) the default values for numericInputs are not updated. I created a minimal example:
In the tabPanel 'Regression' the default values for two numericInputs are supposed to be adjusted to the user's choice of the preconfiguration which decides on the number of latent and manifest variables. Unfortunately only one value is updated, the other one takes on the default value initially specified in numericInput. To make it clear In I changed the order of the conditions in ui.R.
My guess regarding what happens: All values are updated in the server and passed on to the ui. Here they are also updated. If the condition that is consistent with the preconfiguration (number of variables) comes first the numbers of variables are updated and then the default values are updated. Good. But if the first condition is not consistent with the preconfiguration maybe first the default values get updated and afterwards the numbers of variables so that the original default values are shown again. Or what does actually happen? And how can I solve the problem?

```
    library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons(inputId="conf", label="Chose preconfiguration", 
                   choices=c("preconfigA"="preconf_A", 
                             "preconfigB"="preconf_B", 
                             "Standard"="standard")),
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Independent Variables",
                 # number of latent covariates
                 fluidRow(column(5, p("Number of latent covariates")),
                          column(4, numericInput("n_l_cov", label=NULL, value=1,
                                                 min = 0, max = 2, width='60%'))),
                 # number of manifest covariates
                 fluidRow(column(5, p("Number of manifest covariates")),
                          column(4, numericInput("n_m_cov", label=NULL, value=1,
                                                 min = 0, max = 2, width='60%')))),
        tabPanel('Regression',
                 ####
                 h5("Here the conditional Panel with 1 manifest and 1 latent covariate comes first"),
                 conditionalPanel(
                   condition = "input.n_m_cov == 1 & input.n_l_cov == 1",
                   numericInput(inputId="gamma000", label="\u03B3_000", value=0.2, width='100%')
                 ),
                 conditionalPanel(
                   condition = "input.n_m_cov == 0 & input.n_l_cov == 2",
                   numericInput(inputId="gamma000", label="\u03B3_000", value=0.2, width='100%')
                 ),
                 ####
                 h5("Now the first conditional Panel is with 0 manifest and 2 latent covariates"),
                 conditionalPanel(
                   condition = "input.n_m_cov == 0 & input.n_l_cov == 2",
                   numericInput(inputId="gamma100", label="\u03B3_100", value=0.2, width='100%')
                 ),
                 conditionalPanel(
                   condition = "input.n_m_cov == 1 & input.n_l_cov == 1",
                   numericInput(inputId="gamma100", label="\u03B3_100", value=0.2, width='100%')
                 )

      )
    )
  ),
  mainPanel()
)
)  
)


shinyServer(
 function(input, output, session){
  observe({
  c <- input$conf
  print(c)

  if(c=="preconf_A"){
    # set number of manifest covariate to 1
    updateNumericInput(session, inputId="n_m_cov", value=1)
    # set number of latent covariate to 1
    updateNumericInput(session, inputId="n_l_cov", value=1)
    updateNumericInput(session, inputId="gamma000", value=66)
    updateNumericInput(session, inputId="gamma100", value=66)

  }else if(c=="preconf_B"){
    # set number of manifest covariates to 0
    updateNumericInput(session, inputId="n_m_cov", value=0)
    # set number of latent covariate to 1
    updateNumericInput(session, inputId="n_l_cov", value=2)
    updateNumericInput(session, inputId="gamma000", value=5000)
    updateNumericInput(session, inputId="gamma100", value=5000)
  }else{
    NULL
  }
})
})
```

Comment: You seem to have two `numericInputs` with same `inputId`. My guess is that this is what is causing this inconsistency.

Comment: Well, the whole program is more complex with more coefficients aked per condition (one baseline function and one effect function, so these are two intercepts and two coefficients per variable). If I were using conditions like "input.n_m_cov > 0" and then "input.n_m_cov > 1" and built up the whole thing iteratively the problem whould be the layout. Because right now the it looks like this: gamma000 + gamma001*Z1 + gamma002*Z2 + gamma003*Xi1 + gamma 100 + gamma101*Z1 + gamma102*Z2 + gamma103*Xi1 + (mean(epsilon), sd(epsilon)). This is in case of 2 manifest and 1 latent variable.

Comment: Wouldn't using `uiOutput` and `renderUI` help?